# Cross app tracking phonegap application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, tracking

i have 2 different apps in the appstore, i am saving some data in a database (sql) like uid, ip, what page the user is on etc.

Is there a way to give a unique visitor an id or something like that so i can track the users activity in both apps.

And is it possible to see what buttons the user is clicking on.

I have added google analytics to the app but i only can see that there is a user on com.example.mainactivity and not the html pages that are the app.

Hope you guys understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google analytics to solve this problem with two different approaches. You can use the built in [userId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/user-id) feature and it will even keep track of cross device sessions.

```
/**
 * An example method called when a user signs in to an authentication system.
 * @param User user represents a generic User object returned by an authentication system on sign in.
 */
public void onUserSignIn(User user) {
  // Be careful when creating new trackers -- it is possible to create multiple trackers for the
  // same tracking Id.
  Tracker t = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker("UA-XXXX-Y");

  // You only need to set User ID on a tracker once. By setting it on the tracker, the ID will be
  // sent with all subsequent hits.
  t.set("&uid", user.getId());

  // This hit will be sent with the User ID value and be visible in User-ID-enabled views (profiles).
  t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("UX").setAction("User Sign In").build());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Data Import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport) feature to import external user infromation from multiple sources such as CRM data base and your SQL data base and you need to map their user representations to your own custom dimensions. You can follow the example in "[Importing User Data to create AdWords Remarketing Lists](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user)" article. It shows how to use a custom dimension to represent a user id, and then upload even more custom dimensions about that user.

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'NNNN'); // Where NNNN represents the CRM User Id.
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Remember though Google Analytics does not support sending Personally Identifiable information, [see the TOS](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html).